# sql - get parent values based on id

Tags: sql

I have a table named as employee

employee table fields and sample values

```
--------------------------------
id      name     parentid
--------------------------------
1       suresh    null
--------------------------------
2       ram       1
--------------------------------
3       ravi      2
--------------------------------
4       raju      3
--------------------------------
```

Here I need to take the name field value of current, parent and grand parent values for given id value. I need the output as below

Assume the input id is 4 then my expected output is

```
name    parentName    grandParentName
-----------------------------------------
raju    ravi           ram
-----------------------------------------
```

How can I write query for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question!  This is tested and works.

```
select my.`name`, p.`name` as 'parent name', gp.`name` as 'grandparent name'
from employee my 
left outer join employee p on p.id=my.parentid 
left outer join employee gp on gp.id = p.parentid
where my.`id`=4
```

Comment: Don't you have to use LEFT JOIN to avoid losing a 'parent' in the event that parentId is null?

Comment: I don't think "LEFT JOIN" would do the trick.  But a "LEFT OUTER JOIN" would.

Comment: Ummm... LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are the same thing.

Comment: I stand corrected.  Left join and left outer join are indeed the same in mysql.  [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj18922.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here ya go..

```
select e1.name, e2.name as parentName, e3.name as grandParentName
from employee e1
left join employee e2 on e1.parentId = e2.id
left join employee e3 on e2.parentId = e3.id

where e1.id = 4
```